# How to turn shapefiles into raster and aggregate them into one raster

Tags: shapefile, r, rasterization

For example i tried this but it doesn't work

```
rast_a<-raster(extent(shp_1))
res(rast_a)=100
rsh<-rasterize(shp_1,rast_a)
rast_b<-raster(extent(shp_2))
res(rast_b)=100
rshs<-rasterize(shp_2,rast_b)
rast_c<-raster(extent(shp_3))
res(rast_c)=100
rsx<-rasterize(shp_3,rast_c)
co<-rsh+rshs+rsx
plot(co)
```

it returns

```
Error in compareRaster(e1, e2, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, crs = TRUE,  : 
different origin
```

Comment: You are attempting to add the rasters. You need to mosaic them using the raster packages "mosaic()" function.

Comment: at what point of the above code should i use the mosaic function?Checked the help but encountered difficulties. Elaborate

Comment: You should not be forcing the extent and resolution using "res" and "extent". Just rasterize, using your reference raster "rast_a", which I assume represents the entire extent and desired resolution, and then mosaic the results.

Comment: i cant really grasp what you are saying since without the "res", "rast_a" doesn't have the resolution info. Also, i have three shps that i have to combine after i turn them into raster and i don't know how to do it with mosaic. An example would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Generally, the OP has to provide a reproducible example, not the opposite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple reproducible example. I give 2 approaches, one using `mosaic`/`merge` and another that just does the initial `rasterize` at the total extent of all shapefiles combined. The results are the same.

Added based on Jeffrey Evans comment: You also need to consider what to do when you have overlapping polygons. If you want to apply a function (e.g. sum, mean, min, max) to the input rasters to get the output use `mosaic`. If you want the output to be based on the order of input rasters, use `merge`.

```
library(raster)
# Example polygons
p1 <- rbind(c(-180,-20), c(-140,55), c(10, 0), c(-140,-60), c(-180,-20))
hole <- rbind(c(-150,-20), c(-100,-10), c(-110,20), c(-150,-20))
p1 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(p1), Polygon(hole, hole=TRUE)), 1)))
p2 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(rbind(c(-10,0), c(140,60), c(160,0), c(140,-55), c(-10,0)))), 2)))
p3 <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(rbind(c(-125,0), c(0,60), c(40,5), c(15,-45), c(-125,0)))), 3)))
# Add some fake data
p1 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p1, data=data.frame(val=1), match.ID=F)
p2 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p2, data=data.frame(val=2), match.ID=F)
p3 <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(p3, data=data.frame(val=3), match.ID=F)

# Method 1: rasterize at full extent of all shapefile
e <- union(union(extent(p1), extent(p2)), extent(p3))
r <- raster(e, res=1)
r1a <- rasterize(p1, r, field='val')
r2a <- rasterize(p2, r, field='val')
r3a <- rasterize(p3, r, field='val')
rsum <- sum(r1a, r2a, r3a, na.rm=T)

plot(e, axes=F, xlab='', ylab='')
plot(p1, add=T, col='red')
plot(p2, add=T, col='blue')
plot(p3, add=T, col='green')
plot(rsum)

# Method 2: rasterize at extents of individual shapefiles
r1b <- rasterize(p1, raster(extent(p1), res=1), field='val')
r2b <- rasterize(p2, raster(extent(p2), res=1), field='val')
r3b <- rasterize(p3, raster(extent(p3), res=1), field='val')
# Mosaic together, summing values that overlap
# Change the fun parameter to mean, min, or max as necessary
rMosaic <- mosaic(r1b, r2b, r3b, fun=sum, na.rm=T)

# Check that they're the same
cellStats( ((rMosaic - rsum) != 0), sum)

# Method 3: if you want outcome of an overlap to be determined by order instead of a function
# In the case of an overlap, the value is assigned based on order of arguments in merge
rMerge <- merge(r1a, r2a, r3a)
plot(rMerge)
```

Polygons:
[image: Imgur]
Using `mosiac` and summing input rasters:
[image: Imgur]
Using `merge`:
[image: Imgur]

Comment: Nice job. One more option is the merge function in raster. This is the same as mosaic but does not require a function and orders overlap values on order of input. For the most part you do not want to sum rasters to mosaic them. In your example, overlap values represent the sum of the overlap which, is not always desirable. The difference is a max value of 6 vs a mean of 3. For mosaic operations you often want the mean, min or max. Contrary to the OP's example, I am not confident that they actually want the sum of the overlap.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't really clear what the difference between `mosaic` and `merge` was. I've edited the original post to incorporate both these functions. Thanks!

Comment: @MattSM i need clarifications, why you need the rbind?how many vectors you have inside the binds and why those numbers. Too complicated.Lots of questions.i cant implement it on my own problem. Thanks

Comment: @gsa I'm just generating some made up data to create a reproducible example. The bit of code you posted isn't very useful because you don't provide any information on what shp_1, shp_2, and shp_3 are. You'll want to start with the line `e <- union(union(extent(p1), extent(p2)), extent(p3))` and just replace p1, p2, and p3 with your shapefiles (shp_1, shp_2, shp_3)

Comment: okay,now its more clear. the "val" field what is it supposed to contain? and is it obligatory to add a "field" parameter when we rasterize? May i guess that in this position we put a "field that is common between all the shapefiles?

Comment: @gsa Yes, `val` is the attribute from the shapefile that you want to appear in the raster cells when you `rasterize`. It would likely be an attribute shared between all the shapefiles, but it could be a different attribute for each shapefile. It could also be a constant, for example `rasterize(p1, r, field=1)` would make any raster cells covered by shapefile p1 equal to 1. You also need to think about how you want to combine values of overlapping shapefiles. It would be useful if you explained exactly what you're trying to do, your question is extremely vague so it's hard to help.

Comment: @MattSM Here's the deal, i have 3 shps.In each shp i've created a column called "ratings" and put in 0 for each of the shps in this column. Now i have to convert them into raster and combine them into one raster.That raster in the end should display each category according to the "ratings" column, with different colour. Now i did what u did and put as a filed the "ratings" column but the result wasn't right. What do u think?

Comment: Since you set ratings to 0 for _all_ the rasters there's nothing to distinguish them when you rasterize. You should give a different value for each shapefile for ratings. Then, when you call `rasterize` use `field='ratings'`. Finally, to combine them, you'll want to use Method 3 above, which uses `merge` instead of `mosaic`. This is more appropriate for categorical data, which you have. If the shapefiles overlap, the raster value is assigned based on the order of arguments in `merge`.

Comment: So in order to do the merge i have to either write the first method until r3a and then add the rMerge part with the plot following after or the second method until the r3b and then the rMerge part with the plot following after? how do i manage the colours that way since i dont define it anywhere?

Comment: In your case, probably best to skip method 1 entirely. Run the  lines starting with `r1b`, `r2b`, and `r3b` then run the `rMerge` line. Plotting was not part of the question, but you could consult this question for plotting categorical rasters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136330/legend-of-a-raster-map-with-categorical-data

Comment: i did what u said, started with r1b,etc then rMerge and the plot and it says :Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig = TRUE,  : 
  different origin

Comment: Don't know that I'm going to be able to help unless you post a reproducible example. I'll offer one more suggestion: try running the 5 lines from `e <-` to `r3a <-`, then run `rMerge <- merge(r1a, r2a, r3a)` and `plot`.

Comment: They say patience is a virtue, and you are definitely have it. Thank you for all your valuable teaching, i learned a whole lot.

Comment: @gsa Glad to hear it finally worked!

Comment: @MattSM Can you inform me with how you knew what numeric values were needed in the vectors to draw a triangle shaped polygon and how to create geometric shapes out of thin air like you did in general? like square polygons etc?

Comment: I took that example from the `raster` package help. You can look at `?Polygon` and `?SpatialPolygons` to get help. It's a bit tricky because `SpatialPolygons` objects are made up of `Polygons` objects, which are made up of `Polygon` objects. In general, I only ever do this to create simple reproducible examples like I did above.

Comment: yes i saw it while checking the ?SpatialPolygons but i already had asked you haha.Any way if i wanted to rasterize each one shp without performing union first off and aggregate them after how would do that? [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/144461/rasterize-and-union-problem)