# Rasterize and union problem

Tags: shapefile, r, rasterization

i've done the union first and then rasterized it. But now i want instead of that, to rasterize each one and then merge it as one. How do i do that? I mean  without the union first off.

```
 on<-union(union(extent(shp1),extent(shp2)),extent(shp3))
 r<-raster(on,res=100)
 r1<-rasterize(shp1,r,field="vat")
 r2<-rasterize(shp2,r,field="vat")
 r3<-rasterize(shp3,r,field="vat")
 raMerge <- merge(r3, r2, r1, fun=sum, na.rm=T)
```

i turned it to :

```
ra1<-raster(shp1,res=100)
ra2<-raster(shp2,res=100)
ra3<-raster(shp3,res=100)
r1<-rasterize(shp1,ra1,field="vat")
r2<-rasterize(shp2,ra2,field="vat")
r3<-rasterize(shp3,ra3,field="vat")
merge<-r1&r2&r3
```

but says

```
 Error in r1 & r2 : 
 Cannot compare Rasters that have different BasicRaster attributes. See compare()
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about what end result you're trying to obtain? I don't have your shapefiles to test, but I'm assuming simply changing the order of commands isn't what you want!

Comment: I want to aggregate them with the logical operator "&" (and).